# Sonar scan bug: Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to "true"; some subsequent code is never executed

Tags: node.js, sonarqube

```
 router.get('/loginCall', function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('auth0', function (err, user, info) {
    .......some_code_here;
    res.redirect("http://localhost:8080/" || '/user');
  })
})
```

SonarQube is giving this error in line `res.redirect("http://localhost:8080/" || '/user');`.
If I want to have both /localhost and /user in this statement, how can I modify this statement so that sonar will not consider it as a bug?

Comment: What is this statement supposed to do? Right now, it will always redirect to `http://localhost:8080/`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It will always redirect to `http://localhost:8080/`. We can have condition that if user exists, then redirect to `/user` else redirect to `/localhost`.